# Gnuplot polar radial axis style

Tags: gnuplot

How does one remove or adjust the style of the radial axis line when plotting in polar coordinates using Gnuplot?

Example:

```
set polar
unset key
unset border
unset tics
plot '' u w filledcurve
```

Produces:

[image]

I want to remove/adjust the horizontal black line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `unset raxis`, e.g.:

```
set polar
unset key
unset border
unset tics
unset raxis
set size square
plot 1+cos(t) with filledcurve
```

I added `set size square` to use square ratio. The above script results in:

[image: Plot of cardoid function]